Burn address or active wallet?
I have a supposed token c/a airdrop that isn’t passing the sniff test.
Long question short;
I’ve been given a Solana wallet address and been told it’s the burn address for a memecoin that was rugged, and sending my tokens to it will result in the new CTO token being airdropped to me.
My sniff test fails as I can’t be sure if the wallet I’m sending to is accessible (ie does someone have its key), and by sending tokens there…will I be burning or just adding to a scammers wallet.
So the question; is there a way to identify if the wallet is a burn address, or active wallet?
Thanks!
